# Spring's SwitchUserFilter loses user information after redirect

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a question in relation with the combination of SwitchUser filter and authentication.

What I'm trying to achieve is to impersonate an existing user with the help of another user with elevated rights.
I was happy to find out that we can make use of the `SwitchUserFilter` provided by Spring Security, but when I tried to adapt it to my project and workflow it did not work as expected.

I have the following setup:

```java
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public TokenAuthenticationFilter tokenAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new TokenAuthenticationFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public SwitchUserFilter switchUserFilter() {
        var filter = new SwitchUserFilter();
        filter.setUserDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
        filter.setSwitchUserUrl("/impersonate");
        filter.setSwitchFailureUrl("/switchUser");
        filter.setTargetUrl("/user"); // this is already implemented in my app (GET /user)
        return filter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
// I've stripped this to the bare minimum which reproduces my flow
// usually I also configure authenticated access to endpoints & other security related configurations
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.addFilterBefore(tokenAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.addFilterAfter(switchUserFilter(), FilterSecurityInterceptor.class);
    }
```

where

```java
public class TokenAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private TokenProvider tokenProvider;

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String jwt = getJwtFromRequest(request);

            if (StringUtils.hasText(jwt) && tokenProvider.validateToken(jwt)) {
                Long userId = tokenProvider.getUserIdFromToken(jwt);

                UserDetails userDetails = customUserDetailsService.loadUserById(userId);
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("Could not set user authentication in security context", ex);
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }


}
```

In the token I save the user id, and the user details service performs a findById in user's database.

The flow I perform is as follows:

1. login into application (call endpoint, use authentication manager to authenticate based on username/pass, generate token and return it)
2. call `/impersonate?username=anotherUser` with the Bearer token from previous step
3. the application reaches `TokenAuthenticationFilter`, decodes the token, finds the user in the database and updates the security context
4. after that it reaches the `SwitchUserFilter` where it performs the switch (finds user in database, creates user details and finally updates security context)

---  until this point everything works fine ---

5. the SwitchUser filter is configured to redirect to `GET /user`
6. in debug mode I see that at this point, we reach again step 3 (decode token, find user in db, update security context), but it does not perform the switch
7. application reaches `GET /user` with the updated user from previous step (original user, not the switched one)

My question is - how is this combo of authenticating users and switch user filter is supposed to work?
I feel that the flow is kinda natural and normal, the redirect and subsequent requests that will be made from outside need to be authenticated based on the bearer token.
How is this supposed to work? What am I missing/doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: *in debug mode I see that at this point, we reach again step 3 (decode token, find user in db, update security context), but it does not perform the switch* This step should not be executed, because it changes the user back to the old one. Change your imeplemtation of  `TokenAuthenticationFilter`.

Comment: @dur - I know, that's why that line is under the "until this point everything works fine" :). How should the implementation change? I want to be able to have a stateless application and be able to have multiple instances of the app serving this kind of requests. Maybe I should generate another token with extra info and then the third party should make use of it. But that basically defeats the purpose of SwitchUserFilter and I have to re-implement it all by myself.

Comment: AFAIK you can't use `SwitchUserFilter` in a stateless application. It is form based.

Comment: You would need to write your own `SwitchUserFilter` changing the default implementation: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/switchuser/SwitchUserFilter.java. This filter needs to be applied every request and switch the user every request.